# Run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details . While Installing NPM?

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, node-modules

*I'm trying to install npm by using command line in windows 10 but it is not installing instead it gives error as :*

**updated 2 packages and audited 3090 packages in 21.506s
found 133 vulnerabilities (27 moderate, 74 high, 32 critical)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details**

*In below figure we can see in command line:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What that means is that the packages that you have installed have security vulnerabilities (133 to be exact). NPM is offering to try and fix them for you, while the other warnings of missing dependencies mean you have to fix them yourself.

Run `npm audit fix` to fix the errors, or, if you have a package.json with the dependencies you need, then delete your node_modules folder and then run `npm i` in the directory containing your package.json file to reinstall them.

Also, I would recommend checking them and making sure that the dependencies are up to date (they probably aren't).

Comment: Can you elaborate it in  Details ?

Comment: Basically, npm has found flaws in the dependencies that need to be fixed. Usually this means that the creator of the package updated the package, and released a new version that fixes those security vulnerabilities. So, npm is telling you that you need to update your packages to the latest version.

Comment: hey i followed your instructions but  your instruction was not fruitful . Elaborate it in stepwise . I'm new to programming man ?

Comment: What `npm install` does is install all of the dependencies listed in your package.json. So when you ran `npm install`, then it was not installing npm, but installing all of the packages that were listed. So if you want to install npm, you would need to install the npm package by running `npm install -g npm`. in that, you are installing the npm package globally and you can then use it in your projects.

Comment: The warnings mean that some of your dependencies are out of date, and that you need to update them to the latest versions.